# Unpack C Struct in Python

Tags: python, struct

Assuming struct is:

```
typedef struct _MY_STRUCT_INFO
{ 
    UINT64 prop1
    char prop2[1]
}_MY_STRUCT_INFO;
```

What should be the format string in Python struct to unpack the packed string for this struct?

Comment: Depends on your compiler options, target architecture, active `#pragma`s, etc; there's no narrow answer that's guaranteed to be correct. (`Q` is *typically* the right thing for `UINT64`, and a char is `c`, but details matter; this question isn't canonically answerable as-given).

Comment: I think @CharlesDuffy is on the right track. 'Qc' should be your format, but the big question is the Endian-ness of your system.